# how to enable post method in openresty

Tags: openresty

when I want to upload a picture with openresty backend, the server side shows 405 method not allowed, this is the curl:

```
➜  ~ curl 'https://zj.example.top/snap/upload' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynh7LVePlxCWGPohC' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: https://zj.example.top' \
  -H 'Referer: https://zj.example.top/' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
  -H 'x-request-id: d20d67d4-c52d-44cb-9ccd-8fd6d0879e0e' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundarynh7LVePlxCWGPohC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="OIP-C.jpeg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarynh7LVePlxCWGPohC--\r\n' \
  --compressed
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

I have already tried to add `allow all;` config in nginx but still could not fixed this issue:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  zj.example.top;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem;
    allow all;
    if ($allowed = 0) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 1m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 192.210.203.237;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location ^~ /snap {
        allow all;
        client_max_body_size 500k;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

what should I do to allow the post in openresty? this is the openresty version info:

```
[root@k8smasterone curl-8.0.1]# /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -V
nginx version: openresty/1.21.4.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx --with-cc-opt=-O2 --add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.3.1 --add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.62 --add-module=../xss-nginx-module-0.06 --add-module=../ngx_coolkit-0.2 --add-module=../set-misc-nginx-module-0.33 --add-module=../form-input-nginx-module-0.12 --add-module=../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.09 --add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.32 --add-module=../ngx_lua-0.10.21 --add-module=../ngx_lua_upstream-0.07 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.33 --add-module=../array-var-nginx-module-0.05 --add-module=../memc-nginx-module-0.19 --add-module=../redis2-nginx-module-0.15 --add-module=../redis-nginx-module-0.3.9 --add-module=../rds-json-nginx-module-0.15 --add-module=../rds-csv-nginx-module-0.09 --add-module=../ngx_stream_lua-0.0.11 --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib --with-http_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the backend app that issues this error. So the nginx on `:8000` issues this error.

---

Your curl response contains the line

```html
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
```

while the answer from my openresty (at the same 1.21.4.1 version as you got) contains

```html
<hr><center>openresty</center>
```

<sup>(this is true for `server_tokens` set `on` AND `off`, while `on` just appends the version)</sup>

So (1) the version does not match (`1.21.4.1 != 1.21.1`) and (2) the app name does not match (`nginx != openresty`).